# I can access the Fitness site without being logged in

Tags: bug, status-declined, private-beta

I logged out of the Fitness.se site, cleared my cache and, look, I am on it but not logged in. Just to let you know the site is in private beta for two more days.

[image: On the Fitness.SE site in private beta after clearing the cache!]

I click on meta not logged in, and I can still see the site.

Comment: Try clearing your cookies...

Comment: @Shog9 I did but I can still see every page.

Comment: It may be this issue, check out Kevin's answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62830/undesired-auto-login-to-meta

Comment: Keep in mind that "private" betas are still world readable via the API.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We don't use cookies to secure this site due to the number of calories that are in a cookie. We will however allow access to those who have an over abundance of calories.

Comment: But those are probably not the "expert audience" the site is craving for? I can see your point about the cookies, though. (Although you can work wonders calorie-wise by restricting them to certain sub-directories and limiting expiry time.)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't actually clear your cache (both HTML 5 local storage and cookies) all the way. If you did, you would not have access.

When I log in with IE9, then

1. log out using the "Log Out Everywhere" button
2. clear my cache via Tools | Delete Browsing History

.. I indeed lose access to the private beta. You will too.

Answer (score 0):

Great! Now I know I need some fitness too.

[image]